# ARCore App terminates after revoking camera permissions from android settings

Tags: android, arcore

Like the title of my question already tells:

I got an android app which makes use of ARCore. 
I make also use of ARCores Sceneform. 
Everything works fine but when I tested my app I went to the android settings while my ARCore app was running in the background, revoked the camera permissions and my app immediately stopped running without any error message.

In the Android Studio log I only get the message 'Application terminated'.

[image: 'Error message' in android studio]

On my phone the app just closes without any message.

How can I prevent this?

I got this error with ARCore 1.3 and 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml probably you has this line `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>` put as **false**

Then on your **onResume** activity you need to create a function to **check** the permissions, **ask** for permissions if don't has and deal with the **exception** when the user don't give or remove the permissions.

More info how check, ask and handl permissions:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java